# VTune -- viewing results from Linux on OSX with source code

Tags: intel-vtune

I'm running VTune on Linux and collecting results fine. I'm able to open the VTune gui over X and see the results correctly. However, it's slow -- so I'm trying to view the results using my VTune for OSX client. My understanding from the docs is that this is possible. However, while I'm able to see summary stats such as how long the program took to run, how many threads it had, etc., I'm not able to see symbols from the source, and the Bottom-Up tab is completely empty. I think this is due to the fact that VTune is looking for source code and debug info at a path that doesn't exist on my mac (but does on my linux machine). I'm simply copying over the entire output directory from VTune, which includes the amplxe file, and archive, config, data.0, log, and sqlite-db directories.

What is the recommended way to view VTune output data on the OSX client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VTune result was finalized on the target system, it can be viewed on any other system, e.g. on OSX - you need to copy entire result directory and open it in VTune. Symbol files are needed during the [finalization process](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-help-finalization) only. Source files - when you attempt to drill down to source view.

Empty Bottom-Up looks strange, you should probably submit a bug through VTune support. Before doing this please make sure you're using the most recent VTune version.

Please note also you can collect from the target Linux directly using VTune GUI on OSX via [remote connection](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-help-configuring-ssh-access-for-remote-collection).